write/read to/from json a python dict that has a polars DF for one or more keys
I am new to Polars in python. I am trying to save a dict that contains single pl.DataFrames for the values of some of the keys. I am currently trying to save the dict in JSON format, but I am encountering a few problems. Here is a simple statement of the problem:
import polars as pl
import json

df = pl.DataFrame({'x': 1,
                   'y': 2,
                   'z': 3})

data = dict({'K01': ['001', '002', '003'], 
             'K02': {'K11': '1001', 
                     'K12': '1002', 
                     'K13': df
                     }})

data_jsn = json.dumps(data, indent = 4)
# TypeError: Object of type DataFrame is not JSON serializable

The following adjustment corrects this error, but I cannot find a way to recover df.
# write df to json
df_jsn = df.write_json()

# then put df_json into the dict in place of df
data_jsn = dict({'K01': ['001', '002', '003'], 
                 'K02': {'K11': '1001', 
                         'K12': '1002', 
                         'K13': df_jsn
                         }})

data_jsn_ser = json.dumps(data_jsn, indent = 4)
data_jsn_deser = json.loads(data_jsn_ser)

print(data_jsn_deser['K02']['K13'])

# {"columns":[{"name":"x","datatype":"Int64","bit_settings":"","values":[1]},{"name":"y","datatype":"Int64","bit_settings":"","values":[2]},{"name":"z","datatype":"Int64","bit_settings":"","values":[3]}]}

I have tried to convert the object, data_jsn_deser['K02']['K13'], to a pl.DataFrame with no luck.

Is there any way to salvage this approach, and/or
Should I be saving my results to file using another method altogether?


polars.from_dict seems to be what you need. Please look into the docs before asking a question.

What is the expected output? Your code produces [{"x":1,"y":2,"z":3}] for me on the latest version of Polars (1.2.1) - https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/pull/16550 is where write_json changed.


Technically it's possible but I wouldn't 2. Yes. Json is not a good format to save dataframes. Try parquet.


I decided not to include the data frames in the dict. In place of each polars DF in the dict, the value for the key is the path (str) to the file that contains the polars DF. The output comprises 1 json file that contains the dict and several parquet files, each containing a polars DF.
